# Convert scalar variable to array containing variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would one convert `5` to `[5]` in JavaScript?
I have a method that uses jQuery's `$.inArray` and I would like it to work if someone just passes in a scalar variable by converting to an array with one entry, which would be the scalar.

Comment: Could you give an example scenario? Do you want to add a variable to the empty array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted a jquery answer then you can use this:

```
jQuery.makeArray( 5 )
```

Comment: Great answer, this will also work for `$.makeArray([5])` (giving `[5]`)

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
function myFunction(scalarValue) {
    if (typeof scalarValue != "object") {
        scalarValue = [scalarValue];
    }
    console.log(scalarValue); // Now an array
}
```

#### Edit

If you know it's a scalar value (that it hasn't already been turned into an array) you can just do this:

```
var scalarArray = [scalarValue];
```

Comment: @Matt why? it doesn't matter if you redefine your initial variable

Comment: I was hoping this already existed in jQuery so I wouldn't have code bloat but I'm probably over thinking it.

Answer (score 4):

```
scalarValue = scalarValue instanceof Array ? scalarValue : [scalarValue]
```